# react-bulma components using Column results in unexpecteed token

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bulma

I have a react component that tries to render two columns:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Section>
       <Container>
          <Columns>
             <Columns.Column size={6}>
               <SearchCard />
             </Columns.Column>

             <Columns.Column size={6}>
               <DocumentCard/>
             </Columns.Column>
          </Columns>
       </Container>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

but this gets the following error:

```
    SyntaxError:...node_modules/react-bulma-components/src/components/columns/components/column.js: Unexpected token (26:2)

  24 |   ...props
  25 | }) => (
> 26 |   <Element
     |   ^
  27 |     {...props}
  28 |     className={classNames(className, 'column', {
  29 |       [`is-${size}`]: size,
```

I have tried to follow the advice of purring section, then container, then columns. but this is a confusing error to pop up. I do not understand this. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the library can you check from where you are importing the components? For the error seems that you are using the src folder.

Depending of your configuration it should be either from `react-bulma-components` or `react-bulma-componets/lib`

Check on the readme the installation instructions